# `directive` not loading in to `ng-view`

Tags: angularjs

I am loading my controller like this:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl :   'js/scripts/views/login.html',
                controller:     'loginCont'
            })
```

works fine. and I decide to add a `directive` in the `login.html`. like this:

```
<h1>I am login here! {{message}} </h1> //message updates from controller
<div loginDir>Testing</div> //css not applied
```

finally i added the `loginDir.js` to my main.html.

here is my `loginDir` function:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myNewApp')
    .directive('loginDir', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            return {
                restrict:'A',
                link : function () {
                    console.log("link called", element); //not consoling
                    element.css({border:'1px solid red'});
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Any one figureout what's i do wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

you must replace `<div loginDir>`

by

```
 <div login-dir>
```

You can get official documentation here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Are you sure your script adding the directive is run? Is the code "consoling"?

Comment: I added the directive js file in to my main html. what else needed?

Comment: maybe the way you registered your angular app and the modules inside it. Can you update your question, adding the script loading your app and linking your modules?

Comment: I find my issue and fixed, can you have a look. if i am wrong can you correct me?

Answer (score 1):

By mistake, as like factory function, i returning a function instead return a object. here is my mupdate:

```
angular.module('myNewApp')
    .directive('loginDir', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) { //wrong! need to remove
            return {
                restrict:'A',
                link : function () {
                    console.log("link called", element); //not consoling
                    element.css({border:'1px solid red'});
                }
            }
        } //need to remove.
    });
```